# Find the function $f(x)$ when $f(f(x))=1-x$, for $x\in [0,1]$

Tags: functions

> The function f(x) is continuous and $f(f(x))=1-x$, for $x\in [0,1]$ then,

> (A) $f(\frac{1}{8})+f(\frac{7}{8})=3$

> (B) $f(\frac{2}{3})+f(\frac{1}{3})=2$

> (C) $f(\frac{5}{6})+f(\frac{1}{6})=1$

> (D) None of These

My approach is as follow $f\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right) = 1 - x \Rightarrow f'\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right) \times f'\left( x \right) =  - 1$

$f'\left( {f\left( 0 \right)} \right) \times f'\left( 0 \right) =  - 1\& f'\left( {f\left( 1 \right)} \right) \times f'\left( 1 \right) =  - 1$

$f\left( {f\left( 0 \right)} \right) = 1;f\left( {f\left( 1 \right)} \right) = 0$

Not able to procced from here

Comment: Why do you assume $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: Let's try to make sure whether [this](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(f(x))%3D1-x%24&p=1) can help you or not?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585901/how-to-prove-that-ffx-x-implies-that-f-is-not-continuous

Answer (score 8):

From $f(f(x)) =1-x$ follows
$$1-f(x)=f(f(f(x)))=f(1-x) .$$
Hence,
$$f(x) +f(1-x) =1$$
for all $x\in[0, 1]$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments. You can use [this](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(f(x))%3D1-x%24&p=1).

Comment: More generally, if $f(f(x))=g(x)$ then $f(g(x))=f(f(f(x)))=g(f(x))$.

Comment: $f(x)+f(1-x)=1$ is necessary but not sufficient condition. This answer does not give full solution of question in the title, only solution to test problem in the text.

Comment: Yes I agree as $f(x)=x, \frac{a^x}{a^x+\sqrt{a}}$ satisfy $f(x)+f(1-x)=1$ but fail to satisfy $ff(x)=1-x$.