# What can be $f$ so that $f(f(x)) = -x$?

Tags: functional-equations

What can be $f$ so that $f^2(x) = -x$ for all $x\in R$?

I know that if $f^2(x) = -x$ then $f(x)$ is injective and $f$ can not be continuous.

But I can not find an example of discontinuous function so that $f^2(x) = -x$ for all $x\in R$.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: $f^2(x)=f\circ f(x)$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312385/continuous-function-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-such-that-ffx-x

Comment: First of all, clarify your notation.  Presumably, $f^2(x) = f(f(x))$.  Second, how do you know that $f$ cannot be continuous?  Finally, what have you tried?

Comment: @amWhy it's clear that the asker is looking for a potentially discontinuous solution.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, but the answer there provides a discontinuous solution as well

Comment: @amWhy Never mind, the top answer is fine

Comment: @MikeEarnest just took a closer look as you commented, thanks

Comment: @sani Look at the first answer to the linked question

Comment: @sani don't just look at titles of duplicates, look at the answers!.

Comment: Thanks to @RobertZ for having found the duplicate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look at the cycle representation of $f\circ f=-x$, there is one fixed element and a bunch of $2$-cycles, So to build a suitable permutation just pair up the $2$-cycles and for each $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ add the $4$-cycle $(a,c,b,d)$.

Comment: In summary, if $A,B$ is a partition of the positive reals and $g:A\rightarrow B$ is a bijection then the permutation with cycles $(a,g(a),-a,-g(a))$ works.