# Is there a real function that satisfies the relation $f(f(x)) = 1-x$?

Tags: functions

As already one user wrote out on Stack Exchange there is a discontinuous function that satisfies the equation $f(f(x)) = -x$. Namely:

[Find a real function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(f(x)) = -x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312385/find-a-real-function-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-such-that-ffx-x/312421#312421)

--> click on the image here to view the function: [g(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZMZp.png)

I also know that the function mentioned in that piece is equal to

$$f(x) = g(x-0.5)+0.5$$

Can anyone help me out on this and find the appropriate f(x)?

Comment: What is $g(x)$?

Comment: g(x) is mentioned in the post I linked in my description, name Hurkyl

Comment: There are at least $2$ different $g(x)$'s on that page

Comment: At the end of Hurkyls post there is a function mentioned that satisfies the equation f(f(x)) = -x. I mean that explicit function

Comment: Please copy the $g$ that you refer to and paste its definition into your post.

Comment: Geometric observation
$$
1-f(x) = f(f(f(x))) = f(1-x),
$$
so $f(x) + f(1-x) = 1$.

Comment: @Sisyphus, you assume $x=f(x)$, your statement final should be $f(1-f^{-1}(x))=1-x$

Comment: Also any solution to $1-f(x) = f(1-x)$ can be written as $f(x) = g(x - 0.5) + 0.5$ where $g$ is odd. But you can't just take any odd function. That's the problem.

Comment: No, @JacobClaassen. $f(1-x) = \{ f(f(x)) = 1-x \} = f(f(f(x))) = \{ f(f(t)) = 1-t, t = f(x) \} = 1 - f(x).$ Nothing is assumed.

Comment: @JacobClaassen, Sisyphus's observation looks correct to me.

Comment: @christhian-grundmann. That's only a solution to $1-f(x) = f(1-x),$ not to the original problem.

Comment: @CristhianGrundmann, that doesn't work, since, for example, we would then have $1=1-0=f(f(0))=f(1/2)=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

The same approach as in the accepted answer to the linked question works.  We have to have $f(\frac 12)=\frac 12$, which makes $f(f(\frac 12))=\frac 12=1-\frac 12$.  Partition the reals greater than $\frac 12$ into disjoint pairs.  Given a pair $(a,b)$ define $$f(a)=b\\ f(b)=1-a\\ f(1-a)=1-b\\f(1-b)=a$$  Then $f(f(1-a))=a=1-(1-a)$ and similarly for $f(f(1-b))=b$ as required.